# Bug in iOS Safari select with optgroup elements

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

Today we found a strange bug in iOS 8.2 Safari when handeling onchange on a select element with optgroups. Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbeWXO

The strange thing is when you have a selected option within a optgroup and you focus the select element it directly triggers an onchange. What it does, it selects the option in front of the selected one.

Example:

```html
<select id="id_test" onchange="alert('WHY?!')">
  <optgroup label="First">
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Other">
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Test 3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Now when you focus this select element it directly alerts "WHY?", this is because for some reason it selects option "Test 2". When you focus it again it will select "Test 1".

Is there some way (apart from not using optgroup) to work around this strange behaviour?

Comment: This btw only happens in iOS 8.2 Safari for iPhone. On my iPad with iOS 8.2 the bug doesn't show. On iOS 8.1 iPhone simulator the bug doesn't show either.